# What is the difference between [ ] and an empty array?

Tags: matlab

For example I have a 1x5 string array. Now I saw some fields are `[]`. What does this mean? And what is the difference between a field which is totally empty?

How can I create such fields?

```
array(1)=[]; 
array(2)=; 
%or
array(3)="";
```

And how can I check if the input of a field is **empty**, **NaN** or **""**?

Comment: A string cannot contain `[]`, but it can contain the string `"[]"`. Is this what you are referring to? Similarly, a string array cannot contain `NaN`, but it can contain the string `"NaN"`. `NaN` is a number, not a string. -- By the way, I edited your question to a state where it made most sense to me, but since I'm not certain about what you're asking, I might have butchered it. Feel free to revert my edit and/or [edit] it to clear up things further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array(1)=[];` means that you're removing the first element of `array` if the variable already exists.

`array(2)=;` is an invalid expression.

`array(3)=""` stores an empty string `""` at the third index of `array`. Since first two indices were not initialized by you in your code snippet, so these two indices will store [`<missing>`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/missing.html). If you had an array of double class, you would have got zeros instead of `<missing>`. Presence of `<missing>` can be checked by [`ismissing`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismissing.html).

In a string array, you cannot have Nan or empty. You can have `""` string though.

---

You can have those elements if you have a cell array instead.

```
array{1} = [];
array{2} = "";
array{3} = NaN;
```

Now presence of `[]`, `""`, and `NaN` in the above cell array can be checked by [`isempty`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html), [`strcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) and [`isnan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) respectively with [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html).